# Google Cloud Platform - AI Notebook is deleted after instance is stopped

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, containers

I've set up an AI Platform Notebook Instance using a custom container with the below Dockerfile. I can access the notebook via the JupyterLabs interface. But, when I save everything and stop the notebook, and then turn it back on. I lose all of my files.

I cannot figure out where to set this in the GCP Console or my Dockerfile.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-3.0.4

ARG NB_USER="root"
ARG NB_UID="1000"
ARG NB_GID="100"

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    python3-pip \
    unzip \
    wget \
    python3-rtree \
    python-numpy \
    git \
    gdal-bin \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /root

RUN mkdir /root/work 

# update pip
RUN python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade \
    && python3 -m pip install wheel \
    && python3 -m pip install pip setuptools \
    && python3 -m pip install notebook==6.0.0 \
    && python3 -m pip install jupyterhub==1.0.0 \
    && python3 -m pip install jupyterlab==1.1.3


RUN python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/toblerity/shapely.git@master#egg=shapely-1.7.1dev \
    && python3 -m pip install rasterio \
    && python3 -m pip install geopandas \
    && python3 -m pip install descartes \
    && python3 -m pip install solaris \
    && python3 -m pip install rio-tiler

EXPOSE 8080


CMD ["jupyter", "lab","--ip", "0.0.0.0", "--allow-root"]

COPY start.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY start-notebook.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY start-singleuser.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY jupyter_notebook_config.py /etc/jupyter/
```

Comment: what issue are you exactly experiencing? For the moment, I used your dockerfile to create a notebook, created a file, stopped machine, restarted it and folder was there. Is this compatible with your observed behaviour? Did I missunderstand? [I have done it through ssh thoguh, not web interface]

Comment: @AlbertAlbesa my issue is that when I use the Dockerfile above, it creates my Notebook, but when I create a file in Jupyter and make some changes to the file, and save them. Then restart my VM instance on AI Platform it looses said file. Perhaps I should try it through SSH.

Comment: I have been having issues on accesing through web, could you try a simple file creation through ssh for error isolation? Maybe it is not related to Dockerfile. Have you tried doing it more than once? (have you created more than one machine and observed same behaviour?)